# JTable.setDefaultEditor() not working but setting to a specific field works.

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablecelleditor

Attempting to use the JTable.setDefaultEditor() but it doesn't seem to activate. 
Setting it specifically to a column works but just not setting it as the default editor. The println command is not returned but is visible when setting to a specific column.

Is there an extra step required when setting a default editor?

```
    import java.awt.*;
    import javax.swing.*;
    import javax.swing.table.TableCellEditor;
    import javax.swing.table.TableColumn;

    public class Main {
      public static void main(String[] argv) throws Exception {

        JFrame myFrame = new JFrame();
        myFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        String columnNames[] = { "Column 1", "Column 2", "Column 3" };

        String dataValues[][] =
        {
                { "12", "234", "67" },
                { "-123", "43", "853" },
                { "93", "89.2", "109" },
                { "279", "9033", "3092" }
            };
        JTable table = new JTable(dataValues, columnNames);
        myFrame.getContentPane().add(table);

        table.setDefaultEditor(String.class, new MyTableCellEditor());
    //    TableColumn col = table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0);
    //    col.setCellEditor(new MyTableCellEditor());
        myFrame.pack();
        myFrame.setVisible(true);
      }
    }

    class MyTableCellEditor extends AbstractCellEditor implements TableCellEditor, FocusListener
    {

        JComponent component = new JTextField();

        public MyTableCellEditor()
        {
             component.addFocusListener(this);  
        }

      public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected,
          int rowIndex, int vColIndex) {
          System.out.println("Inside getTableCellEditorComponent()");
        ((JTextField) component).setText((String) value);

        return component;
      }

      public Object getCellEditorValue() {
        return ((JTextField) component).getText();
      }

        @Override
        public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
            System.out.println("Focus Lost");

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the reasons I don't like `DefaultTableModel`...

If you change `table.setDefaultEditor(String.class, new MyTableCellEditor());` to `table.setDefaultEditor(Object.class, new MyTableCellEditor());`, it will work, however, a better solution would be to override the `getColumnClass` method of the `DefaultTableModel`

```
DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(dataValues, columnNames){

    @Override
    public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
        // You really should be checking the columnIndex and
        // returning the appropriate data type for the column,
        // but you get the idea
        return String.class;
    }

};
JTable table = new JTable(model);
myFrame.getContentPane().add(table);

table.setDefaultEditor(String.class, new MyTableCellEditor());
```

Take a look at [How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) for more details

Comment: Using Object.class worked. Will have to check the URL provided a bit more closely as I previously glanced at that but must have missed some info.

Comment: It's to do with what information `DefaultTableModel` is returning from it's `getColumnClass` by default, hence the second suggestion ;)